# cqlsh command not working through Ansible

Tags: cassandra, ansible

I have below ansible playbook to run specific commands on remote cassandra clusters

```
---
- hosts: newcass
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: True
  serial: 1

  tasks:
    - name: Execute CQLSH
#      shell: 'cqlsh -f /home/ubuntu/abc.cql'
      shell: 'cqlsh -f abc.cql'
#      command: "export CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=true && cqlsh -f /home/ubuntu/abc.cql"
#      command: "cqlsh -f abc.cql"
      args:
        chdir: /home/ubuntu/
      register: cqlsh_result

    - debug:
         msg: "{{ cqlsh_result }}"
```

After running this playbook we are gettig below error

```
{"changed": true, "cmd": "cqlsh -e abc.cql", "delta": "0:00:00.001835", 
"end": "2019-03-22 02:13:41.799578", "failed": true, "rc": 127, "start": 
"2019-03-22 02:13:41.797743", "stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: cqlsh: not found", 
"stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
```

Tried using `command` module as well but it didnt worked
However when tried `cqlsh -f abc.cql` on cassandra servers manually it worked.

What can be done to run this via ansible playbooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `cqlsh.py` and `cqlsh` files are present in `/usr/bin` folder, If not then copy it because it seems you have configure cassandra by extracting tar file.

I faced same problem in my environment.

Also copy `cqlshlib` which in this case you can find in `/etc/cassandra/conf/` and paste it to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`

your above playbooks seems fine it should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the full path to `cqlsh` if it is not in your $PATH environment variable.

Comment: I have already set it  `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/etc/cassandra/bin/cqlsh` and .bashrc entry is `alias cqlsh="/etc/cassandra/bin/cqlsh"`

Comment: when do `which cqlsh` I can see `/usr/bin` , I have aaded in **args** `executable: /usr/bin` after this error changed to `"msg": "[Errno 13] Permission denied"`

Comment: cassandra files are owned by root user ? If yes then the user with which ansible is getting executed is present in sudoers file ?

Comment: I still think using the full path (`/etc/cassandra/bin/cqlsh`) in your shell command is your best bet. This will remove any environment sourcing issues. Also definitely remove `executable: /usr/bin` - this is not helpful and will only cause failures